# python re.sub group: number after \number

Tags: python, regex, numbers, regex-group

How can I replace `foobar` with `foo123bar`?

This doesn't work:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(foo)', r'\1123', 'foobar')
'J3bar'
```

This works:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(foo)', r'\1hi', 'foobar')
'foohibar'
```

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Comment: this question took me quite a long time to find, because it doesn't feature the terms 'capture group' or 'numbered group reference', but I'm here eventually and glad you asked it.

Comment: Your issue is that r'\112' is getting interpreted as the octal literal 0112, ASCII'J', or decimal 74. Can't see how to force the backreference '\1' to get evaluated before string concatenation or `''.join()`

Answer (score 490, accepted):

The answer is:

```
re.sub(r'(foo)', r'\g<1>123', 'foobar')
```

Relevant excerpt from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

> In addition to character escapes and backreferences as described above, `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named `name`, as defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax. `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character `'0'`. The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem I would prefer to match but not capture, by employing the following.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=foo)', r'123', 'foobar')
  #=> 'foo123bar'
```

which replaces the zero-width string after `'foo'` (think between `'foo'` and `'bar'`) with `'123'`. `(?<=foo)` is a *positive lookbehind*.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYnFTN/1)

---

There are of course situations where a capture group is needed, such as

```
re.sub(r'(f\w*o)', r'\g<1>123', 'foobar')
```

Here

```
re.sub(r'(?<=f\w*o)', r'123', 'foobar')
```

does not work because Python's default regex engine does not support variable-length lookbehinds (the alternative [PyPI regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) does, however).