# PYTHON REGEXP to replace recognized pattern with the pattern itself and the replacement?

Tags: python, regex, matching

Text-

**.1. This is just awesome.2. Google just ruined Apple.3. Apple ruined itself!** 
pattern = (dot)(number)(dot)(singlespace)

Imagine you have 30 to 40 sentences with paragraph numbers in the above pattern. A `<p>` tag should be replaced behind THE PARAGRAPH NUMBER! ***USING `re.sub()`***

I want the text to be:

```
</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">1. This is just awesome.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">2. Google just ruined Apple.</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">3. Apple ruined itself!
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984633/python-re-sub-group-number-after-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what matching groups are for in regular expresssions.

What you want is something like this:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'\.(\d+\. )', '</p><p style="text-align: justify;">\\1', old_string)
```