# Asterisk character in Python with parentheses and spaces

Tags: python, replace, asterisk, parentheses

I want to search for a certain string in a file that is followed by another string.

I have the following string:

```
string = 'Hello ) world Reply ( some text ) and some Reply ( more text ) and that is ) it.'
```

and I want to have the string replaced with

```
'Hello ) world some text and some more text and that is ) it.'
```

So basically, I want the `Reply` and the parentheses gone, but I want to keep whatever is inside the parentheses and I want to keep parentheses that do not follow a `Reply (`.  I have tried to use the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791207/using-asterix-character-as-joker-in-python-string-replacement), but they give me trouble when I'm trying to use parentheses and spaces. I've tried to do this with the following code:

```
string = 'Hello world Reply ( some text ) and some Reply ( more text ) and that is it.'
find = '* Reply ( * ) *'
replace = '* * *'
for f,r in zip(find.strip('*').split('*'), replace.strip('*').split('*')):
    string = string.replace(f,r)
print string

Hello world some text and some more text and that is it.
```

Unfortunately, this removes all parentheses. As you can imagine, nested parentheses cause problems when you only want to remove one pair of parentheses, and all closing parentheses are removed.

Is there a way to do this task without removing all closing parentheses? If you need any more info, please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know about regular expressions yet, have a look at it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Maybe the python docs are a bit much for first meetu. Regex is everywhere, not just python so it makes sense to learn it outside of a languages context. [This maybe](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regular expressions for this, take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, more specific, you want the [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method.

I think this is what you want (untested):

```
import re
string = 'Hello ) world Reply ( some text ) and some Reply ( more text ) and that is ) it.'
new_string = re.sub(r"Reply \((.+?)\)",lambda a : a.group(1), string)
```

Give it a try and let me know!

**Some explanation:**

The first parameter of the sub method is the pattern we want to find and substitute, so `r"Reply \((.+?)\)"` matches the pattern you want, Reply followed by something between parenthesis, also note that we [capture](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) the thing between parenthesis. Also notice the [ungreedy](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) operator (?).

The second parameter is a lambda function to generate what is going to replace the pattern, notice that it receives as argument the match object. So we use the captured data by returning group 1 of the match object.

The third parameter is the string we want to search and substitute things at.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the quick response! This works for me, and I was able to prevent double spaces in the resulting string by adding the spaces to `"Reply \( (.+?) \)"` at the right places. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Also you can use `r"Reply \(\s*(.+?)\s*\)"` and it will work with or without the spaces, (it will remove all white spaces in the beginning and in the end of matched content)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you wanted:

```
def Reply(N):

    if N in range(0,len(Replies)):
        return Replies[N]

    Replies = ["some text", "more text"]

    string = "Hello ) world " + Reply(0) + " and some" + Reply(1) + "and that is ) it."

    print(string)
```