# Regex replace with number after capture group?

Tags: regex

I have a regex pattern like this:

```
([0-9]*)xyz
```

I wish to do substitution like this:

```
$10xyz
```

The problem is that the `$1` is a capture group and the `0` is just a number I want to put into the substitution. But regex thinks I'm asking for capture group `$10` instead of `$1` and then a zero after it.

How do I reference a capture group and immediately follow it with a number?

Using JavaScript in this case.

**UPDATE** As pointed out below, my code did work fine. The regex tester I was using was accidentally set to PCRE instead of JavaScript.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What regex dialect (flavor)?

Comment: This is addressed by the following entry in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups": *[How to follow a numbered capture group, such as \1, with a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5984633/3622940)*

Comment: Sorry, using JavaScript. Added that to the message.

Comment: hwnd's comment should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code indeed works just fine. In JavaScript regular expression replacement syntax `$10` references capturing group `10`. However, if group `10` has not been set, group `1` gets inserted then the literal **`0`** afterwards.

```
var r = '123xyz'.replace(/([0-9]*)xyz/, '$10xyz');
console.log(r); //=> "1230xyz"
```

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, the tester I was using was set to use PCRE instead of JS.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does [work](http://jsfiddle.net/76z8kc5y/) unless I'm missing something:

```
var str = "3xyz";
var str1 = str.replace(/([0-9]*)xyz/, "$10xyz");
alert(str1); // alerts 30xyz
```

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, the tester I was using was set to use PCRE instead of JS.