# Python and Regex to convert wrtitten numbers to numeric

Tags: python, regex, replace, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to convert written numbers to numeric values.

For example, to extract millions from this string:

```
text = 'I need $ 150000000, or 150 million,1 millions, 15 Million, 15million, 15Million, 15 m, 15 M, 15m, 15M, 15 MM, 15MM, 5 thousand'
```

To:

```
'I need $ 150000000, or 150000000,1000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 15000000, 5 thousand'
```

I use this function to remove any separators in the numbers first:

```
def foldNumbers(text):
    """ to remove "," or "." from numbers """"
    text = re.sub('(?<=[0-9])\,(?=[0-9])', "", text) # remove commas
    text = re.sub('(?<=[0-9])\.(?=[0-9])', "", text) # remove points
return text
```

And I have written this regex to findall of the possible patterns for common Million notations. This 1) finds digits and does a look ahead for 2) common notation for millions, 3) The "[a-z]?" part is to handle optional "s" on million or millions where I have already removed "'".

```
re.findall(r'(?:[\d\.]+)(?= million[a-z]?|million[a-z]?| Million[a-z]?|Million[a-z]?|m| m|M| M|MM| MM)',text)
```

which correctly matches Million numbers and returns:

```
['150', '1', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15']
```

What I need to do now is to write a replacement pattern to insert "000000" after the digits, or to iterate through and multiply the digits by 100000. I have tried this so far:

```
re.sub(r'(?:[\d\.]+)(?= million[a-z]?|million[a-z]?| Million[a-z]?|Million[a-z]?|m| m|M| M|MM| MM)', "000000 ", text)
```

which returns:

```
'I need $ 150,000,000, or 000000  million,000000  millions, 000000  Million, 000000 million, 000000 Million, 000000  m, 000000  M, 000000 m, 000000 M, 000000  MM, 000000 MM, 5 thousand'
```

I think I need to do a [look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (?<=), however I haven't worked with this before and after several attempts I cant seem to work it through.

FYI: My plan is to tackle "Millions" first and then to replicate the solution for Thousands (K), Billions (B), Trillions (T) and possibly for other units such as distances, currencies etc. I have searched SO and google for any solutions in NLP, text cleaning and mining articles but did not find anything.

Comment: Having done a bit of text parsing, I'd be tempted to use regex to simply tokenize the input string and then work through the individual tokens. That might be easier than lookbehind regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a relatively simple `re.sub`: match

```
(?i)\b(\d+) ?m(?:m|illions?)?\b
```

*capturing* the initial digits in a group, and replace with that group concatenated with 6 zeros:

```
r'\g<1>000000'
```

https://regex101.com/r/IedRP4/1

Code:

```
text = 'I need $ 150000000, or 150 million,1 millions, 15 Million, 15million, 15Million, 15 m, 15 M, 15m, 15M, 15 MM, 15MM, 5 thousand'
output = re.sub(r'(?i)\b(\d+) ?m(?:m|illions?)?\b', r'\g<1>000000', text)
```

(because the group in the replacement is followed by digits, [make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984633/python-re-sub-group-number-after-number) to use `\g<#>` syntax rather than `\#` syntax)

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest, what does the case insensitive (?i) add?

Comment: It allows the pattern to be much more concise when you don't have to alternate between all possible capitalization options