# Regex not extracting correct value from behind

Tags: regex, pandas

For the string = "4/3/09" using

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'([/ ]\d\d)\b', r'19\g<0>')
#or
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'([/ ]\d\d)$', r'19\g<0>')
```

I am getting 4/319/09 but I should get 4/3/1909

My data:

```
date_set = ['04/20/2009', '04/20/09', '4/20/09', '4/3/09',
'Mar-20-2009', 'Mar 20, 2009', 'March 20, 2009', 'Mar. 20, 2009', 
'Mar 20 2009','20 Mar 2009', '20 March 2009', '20 Mar. 2009', 
'20 March, 2009','Mar 20th, 2009', 'Mar 21st, 2009', 'Mar 22nd, 2009',
'Feb 2009', 'Sep 2009', 'Oct 2010',
'6/2008', '12/2009',
'2009', '2010']
```

If there is 2 digit year i need to add 1900. Ex - if year is 09, it should get replaced with 1909

Comment: I have multiple string in which dates are of form yy or yyyy. If it is yy i need to add 1900 to the year

Comment: Ok, after you added more data, this is not your only issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `([/ ]\d\d)\b` pattern matches `/` or space and then 2 digits up to a word boundary,  and `str.replace` replaces the match (here, `/09`) with `19` + the whole match resulting in `4/3` + `19/09` => `4/319/09`.

You need to use

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'([/ ])(\d\d)\b', r'\g<1>19\2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gSnFPC/1)

Here,

- `([/ ])` - Capturing group 1: a `/` or space
- `(\d\d)` - Capturing group 2: two digits
- `\b` - word boundary

The replacement is `r'\g<1>19\2`, i.e. Group 1 (here, an unambiguous backreference to Group 1 is used since the next char in the replacement pattern is a digit, see [python re.sub group: number after \number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984633)) + `19` and Group 2 value (here, `\2` is a regular numeric backreference is used since there is nothing following the pattern).

See [`re.sub` Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

**EDIT**

After you added more data, it seems you need to only match the two digits at the end of the string.

Use

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'([/ ])(\d\d)$', r'\g<1>19\2')
df['dates'] = df['dates'].str.replace(r'(?<=[/ ])(?=\d\d$)', '19')
```

The second line removes the problem wtith backreferences since it uses lookarounds.

Comment: Can you please explain about that \g or suggest a link where I should look up. I didnt understand how it is working

Comment: And this is throwing error error: invalid group reference 2

Comment: @EXODIA Use **my code** that does **NOT** throw any errors. Do not try to alter what I posted. I added all the details and links.

Comment: It worked for this string but now my other stringss are filing.

string - 4/20/09       
output - 4/1920/1909

Comment: it should be 4/20/1909

Comment: @EXODIA See my EDIT

Comment: its working now. Is r'\g<1>19\2 and r'\g<1>19\g<2> same ?

Comment: And how is this working ? replace(r'(?<=[/ ])(?=\d\d$)', '19')

Comment: @EXODIA `r'\g<1>19\2` = `r'\g<1>19\g<2>`. `(?<=[/ ])` only checks but does not consume `/` or space immediately to the left of the current location and `(?=\d\d$)` requires two digits and end of string right after the current location. It matches an empty string between `/` or space and two digits, hence no need for backreferences.

Comment: Thank you for patiently understanding the doubt and explaining it. I understood and I will further go through the links to read further.

Comment: If you could share some links to understand backlinks and look around as you mentioned. It would help me. As I am unaware of these terms

Comment: @EXODIA [See this universal regex reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).