# Regex For Adding Digits Within Alphanumeric In Python

Tags: python, regex

How does one add three digits within an alphanumeric string using regular expressions in Python?

For instance, I want to add three zeroes after the dash sign `-`, but before the last digit in the string, in way to make `A1-1` be `A1-0001` instead.

My guess was:

```py
df['column'].str.replace('(^C3-\d{1)$)', ???)
```

Comment: If there has to be a last digit, you could try `^([A-Z]\d-(?=\d+$))` and replace with `\1000`

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. it looks like you are looking for C3-#{1 where the # is a number. But your example A1-1 doesn;t match that. Can you give a real example of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'^(C3-)(\d)$', r'\g<1>000\2')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ew9ORL/1). If `C` can be any uppercase ASCII letter, replace it with `[A-Z]`.

Or, a bit more generic for 1-3 digit numbers:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'^(C3-)(\d{1,3})$', lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).zfill(4)))
```

**Details**

- `^` - start
- `(C3-)` - Group 1: `C3-`
- `(\d)` - Group 2: a digit (`\d{1,3}` matches 1 to 3 digits)
- `$` - end of string
- `\g<1>` - value of Group 1
- `000` - three zeros
- `\2` - value of Group 2

A Python test:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['C3-1', 'C3-12', 'C3-123', 'C3-1234']})
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'^(C3-)(\d{1,3})$', lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).zfill(4)))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    column
0  C3-0001
1  C3-0012
2  C3-0123
3  C3-1234
```

Comment: I have a question on r'\g<1>000\2' : how come there is only <> for 1 and not for 2 at the end? I am not used to using g<> regex. So can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @SeunghoonJung `\g<>` is an unambiguous version of a `\1` backreference. It is only necessary if there is a number after a backreference. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984633/python-re-sub-group-number-after-number) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative without regular expressions:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['A2-2', 'A3-001', 'C3-1', 'C3-12', 'C3-123', 'C3-1234']})
df
```

Output:

```py
    C
0     A2-2
1   A3-001
2     C3-1
3    C3-12
4   C3-123
5  C3-1234
```

```py
df.C = df.C.apply(lambda _: _[:_.index('-') + 1] + _[_.index('-') + 1:].zfill(4))
df
```

Output:

```py
    C
0  A2-0002
1  A3-0001
2  C3-0001
3  C3-0012
4  C3-0123
5  C3-1234
```