# Code to check the prefix character in string in python

Tags: python

I wonder what is the corresponding code for the following code in python. I want to check the charactares backword in a string. An exampel if I have a str="anything" and i want to add a '2' if the character is vowel and if the prefix is vowel and suffix is vowel so I want to add '2ä before and after the charctar so the result will be str="a0n0y0th0i0ng". I hope that I could clarify it as much as possible. In c++ we can write str.back(), is there anything like this in python?

Comment: I mean add a '0' not '2' sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex replacement.

```
import re

my_str = 'anything'
output = re.sub(r'([aeiouy])', r'0\g<1>0, my_str)
# '0a0n0y0th0i0ng'
```

You could follow that up with, say, `output.strip('0')` to get rid of the character at the front if you really don't want it there.

[`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) takes a regex as its first argument (we submit a capture group for a single letter, which can be any vowel), and the replacement as the second argument. The replacement in this case, `r'0\g<1>0`, literally means to insert `0`, then the captured group 1 (which is the vowel), then another `0` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984688/2648811) for more details).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that.