# Python regex match a pattern for multiple times

Tags: python, regex

I've got a list of strings.

input=`['XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|9999|9999', 'XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|99999|99999', '999|999|999|9999|999', ....]`

This type `'999|999|999|9999|999'` remains unchanged.

I need to replace `9999|9999` with `12|21`

I write this `(?<=BB\|\d\|\d\|\d\|\d\|\S{3}\|\S{4}\|)9{2,9}\|9{2,9}` to match `999|999`. However, there are 4 to 6 `\|\d` in the middle. So how to match `|d` this pattern for multiple times.

Desired result:

`['XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|12|21', 'XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|12|21', '999|999|999|9999|999'...]`

thanks

Comment: Can you give input -> output pairs? This question is hard to understand

Comment: If the string were `'XX=BB|9999|9999|9999'` would the desired result be `'XX=BB|12|21|9999'`?

Comment: the string will not be `XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|9999|9999|9999`

Comment: Is `'9999|9999'` to be replaced with `'12|21'` always preceded by `'|'` and is at the end of the string or is followed by `'|'`?

Comment: The point is repeating |3|3|1|1 in the middle, not the tail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(BB(?:\|\d){4,6}\|[^\s|]{3}\|[^\s|]{4}\|)9{2,9}\|9{2,9}(?!\d)', r'\g<1>12|21', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7uGEz/1).

*Details*:

- `(BB(?:\|\d){4,6}\|[^\s|]{3}\|[^\s|]{4}\|)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `BB` - a `BB` string
  - `(?:\|\d){4,6}` - four, five or six repetitions of `|` and any digit sequence
  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `[^\s|]{3}` - three chars other than whitespace and a pipe
  - `\|[^\s|]{4}\|` - a `|`, four chars other than whitespace and a pipe, and then a pipe char
- `9{2,9}\|9{2,9}` - two to nine `9` chars, `|` and again two to nine `9` chars...
- `(?!\d)` - not followed with another digit (**note** you may remove this if you do not need to check for the digit boundary here. You may also use `(?![^|])` instead if you need to check if there is a `|` char or end of string immediately on the right).

The `\g<1>12|21` replacement includes an [unambiguous backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5984633/3832970) to Group 1 (`\g<1>`) and a `12|21` substring appended to it.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KeZEfX):

```py
import re
texts=['XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|9999|9999', 'XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|99999|99999', '999|999|999|9999|999']
pattern = r'(BB(?:\|\d){4,6}\|[^\s|]{3}\|[^\s|]{4}\|)9{2,9}\|9{2,9}(?!\d)'
repl = r'\g<1>12|21'
for text in texts:
    print( re.sub(pattern, repl, text) )
```

Output:

```
XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|12|21
XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|12|21
999|999|999|9999|999
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `re.sub` here and search for the pattern `\b9{2,9}\|9{2,9}\b`:

```py
inp = ["XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|9999|9999" "XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|99999|99999"]
output = [re.sub(r'\b9{2,9}\|9{2,9}\b', '12|21', i) for i in inp]
print(output)

# ['XX=BB|3|3|1|1|PLP|KLWE|12|21', 'XX=BB|3|3|1|1|2|PLP|KPOK|12|21']
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question clearer.. There are `999|999`, this one remains. not to change it. thanks