# How do I enforce a project to always wrap certain tags with {% raw %} and {% endraw %}?

Tags: python, templating, cookiecutter

I am creating template starters that will work with cookiecutter, a python library.

So inside some of the subfolders of a project, for files of a particular type, usually `.html`, I need any tags that look like this

`{% if blah blah %}`

to be wrapped like this

`{% raw %}{% if blah blah %}{% endraw %}`

The exact tags are uncertain.

They may be

```
{% load blah %}
```

or

```
{% include blah %}
```

or
even an image tag

```
<img class="mx-auto h-12 w-auto" src="{% raw %}{% static 'assets/v-sq.svg' %}{% endraw %}" >
```

I am unsure how to enforce this or autoformat.

Can advise?

### Context about escaping special characters in Cookiecutter

https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/troubleshooting.html#i-m-having-trouble-generating-jinja-templates-from-jinja-templates

Comment: "The exact tags are uncertain". I don't undrestand how would I distingush what to wrap and what not.

Comment: Solved it with `re.sub(r'({\% [^%]+ \%})', '{% raw %}\g<1>{% endraw %}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of ChatGPT3 and some googling to find this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984688/80353)

```py
import re

# Open the file in read mode
with open('file.html', 'r') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file
    text = file.read()

# Use regex to replace all occurrences of the word "apple" (case-insensitive) with "[apple]"
text = re.sub(r'({\% [^%]+ \%})', '{% raw %}\g<1>{% endraw %}', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# Open the file in write mode
with open('file.html', 'w') as file:
    # Write the modified content to the file
    file.write(text)
```

Comment: If you control the template content, then just ... create the files properly in the first place.  I don't understand what use-case you are addressing here.  How would a template ever be created with wrong tag content, such that you would need this fix?

Comment: The content had to be manipulated in order to be usable in a cookiecutter template.

The original content cannot have those `{% raw %}` tags in the final output files generated by a cookiecutter. 

I first got the html template working as a project. Then I have to transfer into the cookiecutter template hence I needed to add those `{% raw %}` tags afterwards for cookiecutter to work

Comment: First of all, the term "template" is ambiguous. As in it can refer to Django templates (which are basically the T in MTV) or it can refer to cookiecutter templates. What I did is: 1. i create the Django template in a Django project as normal. 2. once i am satisfied, i wanted the code in that Django project which includes Django template files to be in a Cookiecutter template (a set of files). 3. everything went well by simply copy and paste except for Django template files because the `{%` will be processed by cookiecutter and the `{% raw %}` is how thye are escaped.

Comment: added context to original question with a link to show that cookiecutter requires `{% raw %}` to escape special characters

Comment: So this is more of a _compilation_ step?

Comment: i guess you can call it that?