# How to remove footnotes anchors ([1]) from a scraped wiki page?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

```
Bigtable,[4] MariaDB[5]
```

How do I use Python re library to remove those [4] quotations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want your output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to remove those scientific quotations

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Bigtable,[4] MariaDB[5]"
>>> re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '', s)
'Bigtable, MariaDB'
```

The regex `\[.*?\]` will match the substrings that starts with `[` and ends with `]` with as few character inside the brackets as possible

If you only want to remove square brackets with numbers inside, use this regex instead: `\[\d+\]`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

It is slightly unclear as to what you want in your output: only drop `[4]` types or drop all quotes, such as... `[4]`, `[5]`.

The following two examples show you how to handle these two scenarios with python. However, if you want to use command line, here is what you can using `echo` + `sed`.

```bash
echo "Bigtable,[4] MariaDB[5]" | sed -E "s/\[[0-9]+\]//gm"

## Output
Bigtable, MariaDB
```

#### Example-1: `Python`

Assuming that you only want to replace citation quotes that are similar to `[4]` and still keep `[5]`, this should work for you.

> See example in [Regex101.com: scenario-1](https://regex101.com/r/gIOvKC/1)

```py
import re

# define regex pattern(s)
pattern1 = r"(?:,\s*)(\[\d+\])(?:(\s*)?)"

# compile regex pattern(s) for speed
pat1 = re.compile(pattern1)

# evaluate regex substitution
result1 = pat1.sub(r',\g<2>', text)

print(result1)
```

> With `,\g<2>` we are replacing `,[4]` with `,` but leaving `[5]` untouched. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984688/8474894) for more details.

**Output**:

```bash
Bigtable, MariaDB[5]
Bigtable, MariaDataBase[15]
Bigtable, GloriaDB[51]
```

#### Example-2: `Python`

Removing all such `[4], [5]` quotations.

> See example in [Regex101.com: scenario-2](https://regex101.com/r/gIOvKC/3)

```py
import re

# define regex pattern(s)
pattern2 = r"(\[\d+\])"

# compile regex pattern(s) for speed
pat2 = re.compile(pattern2)

# evaluate regex substitution
result2 = pat2.sub('', text)

print(result2)
```

**Output**:

```bash
Bigtable, MariaDB
Bigtable, MariaDataBase
Bigtable,  GloriaDB
```

### Dummy Data

```py
# we will use this text for testing the regex
text = """\
Bigtable,[4] MariaDB[5]
Bigtable,[40] MariaDataBase[15]
Bigtable, [14] GloriaDB[51]
"""
```